# How do I call a specific piece of json data in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, json

(sorry for the bad title)
I have this json file

```
[
    {
        "userId": 3017221209,
        "displayName": "Frank"
    }, 
    {
        "userId": 1690049096,
        "displayName": "dumb"
    }
]
```

And I deserialized it with this

```
var userss = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<User>>(json);
```

But I tried to mention it in a foreach loop (like for each user id do this and that) but I couldn't figure it out

```
foreach (var usersstuff in userss) { /* other stuff you are not supposed to see */ }
```

So.. any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use User like a variable if it's name's class, try this:

```cs
foreach (var user in userss) { /* other stuff you are not supposed to see */ }
```

Comment: I forgot that oops but I still can't call the userId in the foreach loop

Comment: can you show the User's class?